# Limit SSH access to specific clients by name (not ip)

Tags: rhel, sshd, ssh-config

I recently migrated one of my servers to a RHEL8 equivalent, which means (i) leaving tcp_wrappers behind (since openssh no longer compiles against libwrap), (ii) no longer have the ease and flexibility of simply tweaking hosts.deny and hosts.allow, and (iii) start wrestling with things like firewalld.

However, for this particular box, the security requirements are very simple:

1. have sshd listen on an alternate port (say, 1234).
2. have 2 'remote' users (with userid on the server of, say, 'fred' and 'barney').
3. user 'fred' lives in sunny California, and uses an ISP where his ip is dynamically allocated on each connection. 'barney' lives in humid Texas - same DHCP story.
4. their ISP's vary the ip blocks with some frequency, so I typically used the ISP name with a wildcard in my hosts.allow file. For example

   ```
   sshd : .calif.isp.net : ALLOW
   sshd : .texas.isp.com : ALLOW
   ```

(for 'fred' and 'barney', respectively).

5. it seems difficult -> impossible to filter by name in firewalld, but...I'm fairly sure I can (in theory) tweak sshd_config to handle just this sort of thing.

In theory...but I'm unsure how to tweak the sshd config file to do this. I already have AllowUser setup to restrict to myself (say, 'wilma', using an ISP from Vermont -  .vermont.com), 'fred' and 'barney'

```
 AllowUsers wilma fred barney
```

but thats only one onion layer. We use password authentication, so my *guess* (which I'm hoping someone can confirm, or correct) is to (i) first turn off password authentication,

```
 PasswordAuthentication no
```

and then (ii) add the following to the bottom of the sshd config file:

```
 Match Address *.calif.isp.net, *.texas.isp.com, *.vermont.com
   PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Is this (even remotely) correct? And, if correct, there a more efficient way to list the matching addresses'? In my example, there are only 3, but suppose instead of 3 I had 300. Is there a way to put all those address in a 'block' somewhere (call it ''friendly'), and then simply use something like

```
 Match Address friendly
   PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't ssh key authentication do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with your assumptions regarding

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

and

```
Match Address *.calif.isp.net, *.texas.isp.com, *.vermont.com
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```

There's no concept of *blocks*, though, so that's a **NO** on `friendly`.

But looking at that scale (300 ISPs? road warriors?) you might start thinking about setting up a VPN with 2FA or similar and force the ssh through that and be more relaxed on the ssh config.